# SignalR Mapping user to connectionID with custom authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, signalr

I am trying to implement a chat application. Users should be able to send messages to specific users. In order to do that I need to map usernames to their connectionIDs.

My client is using custom authentication. Username is stored in Session["User"]. Therefore I don't have the username stored in Context.User.Identity.Name, which is where SignalR normally takes the username from.

How else can I get the username of the logged in user so that I can map it to Context.ConnectionID?

Here is some sample implementation of public class ChatHub : Hub I found on the web.

```
private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public void SendChatMessage(string who, string message)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass your username using query string.

**Client**

First set query string

For auto generated proxy

```
$.connection.hub.qs = { 'username' : 'anik' };
```

For manual proxy

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
connection.qs = { 'username' : 'anik' };
```

then start hub connection

**Server**

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var username= Context.QueryString['username'];
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Comment: Is this dangerous to do from the client? Couldn't a user change this javascript (say they change "anik" to "user2") and the server ends up storing the wrong username? Thanks for the help. Your post was helpful.

Comment: this just an example of how you can do it @user95227

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi yes it's dangerous. What about JWT tokens? they are built for the same case (passing user id to server)